# How can I give Bootstrap select a normal height if there is nothing selected?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using [bootstrap select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) in my page and I need it to be empty by default  `(and value="")` when the page loads (it is a required field so when the user submits the form, the validation message will appear in case it's empty).

It actually works but it looks weird/odd/too flat:

[image]

And this would be the desired result:

[image]

I have used this attribute to make the select look empty: `data-none-selected-text=""` and it actually looks empty but too flat.

If I remove that attribute, I'll get this `Nothing selected` placeholder which I don't want:

[image]

How can I make the design consistent and keep the same size whether something is selected or not?

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Bootstrap Select CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-sm">
        Project Manager <span style="color:red;">*</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm">
        <select class="selectpicker show-tick w-100" data-none-selected-text="" multiple data-max-options="2" aria-label="Project Manager" required>
          <option value="Michal Jackson">Michael Jackson</option>
          <option value="Michael Jordan">Michael Jordan</option>
          <option value="Luke Skywalker">Luke Skywalker</option>
          <option value="Rafael Nadal">Rafael Nadal</option>
          <option value="Cristiano Ronaldo">Cristiano Ronaldo</option>
          <option value="Albert Einstein">Albert Einstein</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Popper.js 5.0.2 JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap 5.0.2 JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- jQuery CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Select JS BETA VERSION, UPDATE TO A STABLE VERSION COMPATIBLE WITH BS5 ONCE IT IS RELEASED-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite default bootstrap class and make an exception for this scenario.

```
.dropdown-toggle {
   height: 50px;
 }
```

Comment: 50px is too tall and you should probably use `min-height` to be more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use placeholder text, just use a blank HTML space (`&nbsp;`) as the `data-none-selected-text` or `placeholder` attribute value. Either approach results in the select box holding a standard height with no visible text in it.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-sm">
        Data Attribute Example <span style="color:red;">*</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm">
        <select class="selectpicker show-tick w-100" data-none-selected-text="&nbsp;" multiple data-max-options="2" aria-label="Project Manager" required>
          <option value="Michal Jackson">Michael Jackson</option>
          <option value="Michael Jordan">Michael Jordan</option>
          <option value="Luke Skywalker">Luke Skywalker</option>
          <option value="Rafael Nadal">Rafael Nadal</option>
          <option value="Cristiano Ronaldo">Cristiano Ronaldo</option>
          <option value="Albert Einstein">Albert Einstein</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-sm">
        Placeholder Example <span style="color:red;">*</span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm">
        <select class="selectpicker show-tick w-100" placeholder="&nbsp;" multiple data-max-options="2" aria-label="Project Manager" required>
          <option value="Michal Jackson">Michael Jackson</option>
          <option value="Michael Jordan">Michael Jordan</option>
          <option value="Luke Skywalker">Luke Skywalker</option>
          <option value="Rafael Nadal">Rafael Nadal</option>
          <option value="Cristiano Ronaldo">Cristiano Ronaldo</option>
          <option value="Albert Einstein">Albert Einstein</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</body>
```